# date() php , отстает на 3 часа

Tags: php

У меня сейчас например 11:03, а используя date(), мне выведет 8:03. Как исправить проблему? Либо как иначе можно получить время?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй в самом коде указать в PHP

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Kiev' );
```

date_default_timezone_set() устанавливает временную зону по умолчанию для всех функций даты/времени в скрипте/коде

Answer (score 2):

Надо у `php.ini` поставить правильную таймзону

```
date.timezone = Europe/Moscow
```

И перезагрузить апач надо на всякий случай

Comment: почему то не помогает

Comment: И перезагрузить апач надо на всякий случай